# Dive into getter/setters

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I want to create objects which they will have an object named `generic_object` as their **prototype object**. `generic_object` must have a **getter/setter** property whose role will be to assign different functions to newly created objects. Virtually, that's the same how accessor property `.onclick` works. We may give different listeners to different DOM elements by just using the setter:

```
elem.onclick=function(){...};
```

I 've constructed the following:

```
var generic_object={
    temp:null,
    set onair(callback){
        callback(); 
        this.temp=callback;
    },
    get onair(){
      return this.temp; 
    }
};

var obj1=Object.create(generic_object);
var obj2=Object.create(generic_object);
obj1.onair=function(){console.log(1);};
obj2.onair=function(){console.log(2);};
```

This does my job, however I want to eliminate `.temp` property because it is being created inside `obj1` and `obj2` as an own property (`.temp` inside generic_object is shadowed) and that's something I do not want.So:

**Question1**: Is it possible to transform the above code and get the same result *without using temp*?

**Question2**: Let's take the previous example.Since `.onair` property never becomes own property of `obj1`, `obj2` (getter/setters are not shadowed), how JS engine tells between `obj1.onair` and `obj2.onair`? Are these function objects stored inside the memory spots reserved for each of the objects `obj1` and `obj2` even, I repeat, these are not their own properties? I am confused about that...

Thank you

Comment: `elem.onclick=function(){...};` has been shown time and time again to be a bad pattern. Step out of the 1990s and embrace a better event pattern.

Comment: Who told you I am using .onclick? I 've mentioned it as a well-known paradigm. This is a completely irrelevant remark!!

Comment: I believe it is relevant. You are trying to make an event architecture that mirrors one used in browsers, but would be removed, were it not for the legacy code that depends on it. Sure, it's a well known paradigm. `Goto` is a well known paradigm. That doesn't mean it's a good paradigm though.

Comment: @spender Ridiculous, this is not the question and anyway that is ridiculous.